# Select multiple distinct rows

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table with following data.

```
id country serial other_column
1  us      123    1
2  us      456    1
3  gb      123    1
4  gb      456    1
5  jp      777    1
6  jp      888    1

7  us      123    2
8  us      456    3
9  gb      456    4
10  us     123    1
11  us     123    1
```

Is there a way to fetch 2 rows per unique country and unique serial?

For example, expecting following results from my query.

us,123,1 comes twice cos there was 3 of the same kind and I want 2 rows per unique country and unique serial.

```
us,123,1
us,123,1 
us,456,1
gb,123,1
gb,456,1
jp,777,1
jp,888,1
```

I can't use:

```
select distinct country, serial from my_table;
```

Since I want 2 rows per distinct value match for country and serial. Pls advice.

Comment: What criteria are you using to signify the "2 rows per unique country and unique serial"? ID #? Serial # ASC/DESC? etc. What if there is more than 2? What stays and what goes?

Comment: @GRIV Can be ASC/DESC, won't matter. It is unique if locale + serial occurs once like us + 123. I want to capture twice of this occurrence. So should print us,123 twice. (I want to capture entire row not just these 2 values)

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, going back to my above comment: ID #7 with us/123/2 is not shown but ID #1 with us/123/1 is shown? Why does "other_column" with a value of 1 return vs. 2? There has to be some logic in your ordering.

Comment: if you have us, 123, 1 and us 123, 1 and us, 123, 2 which ones would you want ? what's the logic

Comment: @trillion us, 123, 1 and us, 123, 1 is fine. There are many more columns. Thus would end up with us,123,1,a,b,c and us,123,1,d,e,f which is what I want. 2 rows for each unique country + serial.

Comment: @karvai does the solution below works for you ? i have added one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `DENSE_RANK` and `ROW_NUMBER` to your data set using a `CTE` or `subquery` then return rows with a `ROW_NUMBER` less than `3` and a `DENSE_RANK` equal to `1`. Also, since you did not specify the `ORDERING`, I've added a custom `ORDER BY` to handle your `Country` sorting to match your desired output above.

```
SELECT
  ID,
  Country, 
  Serial, 
  other_column
FROM 
  (SELECT 
   *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Country, Serial ORDER BY Country, Serial, other_column) AS RN,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Country, Serial ORDER BY Country, Serial, other_column) AS DR
FROM my_table) A
  WHERE RN < 3 AND DR = 1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Country = 'us' THEN 1
              WHEN Country = 'gb' THEN 2
              WHEN Country = 'jp' THEN 3
              ELSE 4
         END ASC, Country, Serial, other_column, ID
```

**Result:**

```
| ID | Country | Serial | other_column  |
|----|---------|--------|---------------|
| 1  | us      | 123    | 1             |
| 10 | us      | 123    | 1             |
| 2  | us      | 456    | 1             |
| 3  | gb      | 123    | 1             |
| 4  | gb      | 456    | 1             |
| 5  | jp      | 777    | 1             |
| 6  | jp      | 888    | 1             |
```

**Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/mm32P-D9).**

Answer (score 1):

- since you didn't specify any logic which rows it should pick based on the 'other column' value (i am assuming it doesn't matter for you).

Having said that, my code will always pick two rows based on unique country and serial with the other_column value as ascending. For example if you have 3 rows:

- us, 123, 1
- us, 123, 1
- us, 123, 2

it will go for first two since other_column value is set to ASC, if you want the other way around you can change the code to `order by DESC` within the partition by clause.

If there are less than 3 rows for the country and serial it would just pick 1 row.

for example

- us, 456, 1
- us, 456, 1
- us, 123, 1
- us, 123, 2
- us, 123, 3

would result in:

- us, 456,1
- us, 123,1
- us, 123,2

```
with main as (
select 
*,
count(*) over(partition by country, serial) as total_occurence,
row_number() over(partition by country, serial order by other_column) as rank_
from <table_name>
),

conditions as (
  select *, 
  case when total_occurence < 3 and rank_ = 1 then true 
       when total_occurence >=3 and rank_ in (1,2) then true else
  false end as is_relevant
from main
)

select * from conditions where is_relevant
```